# proof for matrix norms

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

How do I prove these two inequalities on matrix norms:

1. $\Vert A \Vert_1 \leq n\Vert A \Vert_\infty,$
2. $\Vert A \Vert_1 \leq \sqrt{n}\cdot\Vert A\Vert_F$ , where A is
   $m$-by-$n$ real matrix.

Comment: Please write this in proper Tex.  I have no idea what you are asking.  There is a live preview...

Comment: With the help of a little `\Vert`, I made the question a bit more readable. @Elnaz, what do you know of these matrix norms?

Comment: I know the definitions; they are provided in the Wikipedia, however with no proofs.

Comment: Are you referring to the induced norms or the "entrywise" norms?

Comment: I'm referring to the extension of vector norms to the matrix norms; so yes these are induced norms.

Answer (score 2):

**(1)** Typically, to prove $\|A\|_1 \le C$, you prove
$$ \|Ax\|_1 \le C\|x\|_1 $$
(and then take the sup over $x$ such that $\|x\|_1=1$, or over $x$ such that $\|x\|\ne 0$, whichever you find more convenient).  So we want to show
$$ \|Ax\|_1 \le n\|A\|_\infty \|x\|_1 \tag{a} $$
A typical method of proving an inequality is by a chain of inequalities, like
$$ \|Ax\|_1 \le \dotsm \le \dotsm \le n\|A\|_\infty \|x\|_1 $$
To write such a chain, at some point we'll need to introduce $\|A\|_\infty$ (since it appears at the far right but not on the far left), and to do that, you typically use the fact that
$$ \|Ax\|_\infty \le \|A\|_\infty \|x\|_\infty \tag{b} $$
So we expect to invoke (b) in our proof of (a).  Comparing (b) and (a) suggests the following plan: replace $\|Ax\|_1$ with $\|Ax\|_\infty$ somehow, then invoke (b), then replace $\|x\|_\infty$ with $\|x\|_1$ somehow.  Presumably the $n$ will appear along the way.  This plan calls for some inequalities relating the *vector* norms $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ and $\|\cdot\|_1$; I'll just assume here that we remember the inequalities
$$ \|x\|_\infty \le \|x\|_1 \le n\|x\|_\infty $$
Using these inequalities to carry out our plan yields the following argument:
\begin{align*}
\|Ax\|_1 &\le n\|Ax\|_\infty &&\text{(replace $\|\cdot\|_1$ with $\|\cdot\|_\infty$)}\\
&\le n\|A\|_\infty\|x\|_\infty &&\text{(invoke (b))}\\
&\le n\|A\|_\infty\|x\|_1 &&\text{(replace $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ with $\|\cdot\|_1$)}
\end{align*}
That proves (1).

**(2)** The method used in (1) yields
$$ \|A\|_1 \le \sqrt n \|A\|_2 $$
We'd be done if we could show that
$$ \|A\|_2\le\|A\|_F \tag{c} $$
Since the norm on the left of (c) is an "induced" norm, we expect, as in (1), to prove (c) by showing
$$ \|Ax\|_2\le \|A\|_F\|x\|_2 $$
Writing this out in coordinates:
$$ \Big(\sum_{i=1}^m \Big(\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} x_j\Big)^2\Big)^{1/2} \le \Big(\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}^2\Big)^{1/2} \Big(\sum_{j=1}^n x_j^2\Big)^{1/2} $$
Tidy up by squaring everything:
$$ \sum_{i=1}^m \Big(\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} x_j\Big)^2 \le \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}^2 \sum_{j=1}^n x_j^2 $$
Seeing $\sum_{i=1}^m$ on both sides (and noting that it doesn't matter whether we think of $\sum_{j=1}^n x_j^2$ on the RHS as being inside or outside of the $\sum_{i=1}^m$), we might hope to prove this by proving the termwise inequality
$$ \Big(\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} x_j\Big)^2 \le \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}^2 \sum_{j=1}^n x_j^2 $$
and then summing over $i$.  That doesn't always work, but it's the simplest thing that could possibly work, so we try it first.  And indeed, now we recognize Cauchy-Schwarz (if we didn't before).