# How to prove this inequation (About matrix and vector norm)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, normed-spaces

$\|A\vec{x}\|\leq\|A\|\space\|\vec{x}\|$ where $A$ is a $m\times n$ matrix and $\vec{x}$ is a n-dimensional column vector. Assume that $\|A\|=\sqrt{\Sigma_{i}\Sigma_{j}a_{ij}^{2}}$

Comment: How do you define the matrix norm $\|A\|$?

Comment: What definition for the norm of a matrix are you using?

Comment: Assume that $||A||=\sqrt{\Sigma_{i=1}^{m}\Sigma_{j=1}^{n}{a_{ij}^{2}}}$

Comment: $\max_{\|x\|^2=1} \|A x\|^2 \le \sum_i \|A_{i.}\|^2$. or with the usual notations : $\text{operator norm} = \max_{\|x\|=1} \|A x\| = \|A\| \le \|A\|_F = \sqrt{\sum_i \|A_{i.}\|^2} = \sqrt{\sum_i \sum_j |A_{ij}|^{ 2} } = \text{Frobenius norm}$

Comment: @HaroldH. You should add clarifications to the post, not to the comments. (For example, you should say what is $\|A\|$ and what is $\|\vec x\|$ in your question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using an [induced norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Induced_norm), the inequality is guaranteed by the definition, as noted in the other answers.

From your comment it seems that you are using the Frobenius norm. in this case you can find a proof of the inequality here: [Consistency of matrix norm: $||Ax||_2 \leq ||A||_{Frobenius}||x||_2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/738478/consistency-of-matrix-norm-ax-2-leq-a-frobeniusx-2).

Note that we can also have norms (on the linear operators space) for which the inequality is not true.

Comment: It seems it's a duplicate of another post... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$\|A\| = \sup_{\|x\|=1} \|Ax\|.$$ Your inequality is obviously true if $x =0$. Then, for $x \neq 0$ one has $$\|A\frac{x}{\|x\|}\| \leq \|A\|,$$ because of the sup.

Answer (score 0):

$\sup_{\|y\|\leq 1}\|Ay\| = \|A\|$, which implies that $\|A\| \geq \|Ay\|$ whenever $ \|y\| \leq 1$. This is true for $y= \frac{x}{\|x\|}$. Use one of the properties of a norm and you are done.